# my family set up

Tags: 8.0, parental-control

am an adult  but  unable to download an application.when l get to install,I get this feedback  my family setup must be done.l have opened an account,joined the community but having  same problem downloading. Please help me.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have entered a wrong birthdate for your Microsoft Account. If your lucky you can still change it through the website, otherwise you'll have to contact Microsoft support or create a new account.